# AJAX / Jquery post or get

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm starting to build a calander based on PHP, MySQL, AJAX and Jquery.
My knowledge of the last two are pretty poor, but I'm willing to learn.
I've found this script which does in basic needs what I need, but I've got a question about firing it into an external file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>serialize demo</title>
  <style>
  body, select {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  form {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>

<p><tt id="results"></tt></p>

<script>
  function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
  }
  $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
  $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
showValues(); <----- // how to get these values to call an external file (e.g. cal.php?showValues();)
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

How can I use AJAX / Jquery to send the selected options to an external file cal.php?...
This file will be included in a div.

Comment: [jQuery Learn AJAX](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Comment: Great link, after reading it.. I'm not seeing the way to do it.
Can you give a little hint?

Comment: F12 to open your developer tools, and go to the "Network" tab.  Refresh the page, or do whatever action that should cause the ajax to fire.  Look in the Network tab for the requets and make sure it 1) happens, and 2) it gets a valid response code and the expected response.  https://i.imgur.com/ufdYnTt.png

Comment: That seems to work fine! 
How do I manage to get that back on the screen in a div?
What I've tried to do that doesn't work.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/  There are a few examples on the ajax pages using the different methods, and using their responses.  Currently your snippet below makes the ajax call, but does nothing with the response.

Comment: I've added : 

success: function (str) {
        console.log(str);   
    }, 
That seems to make the console a little quieter ;)
After reading the link you've send me I realy don't see the point what's missing. 
Is there a change you give me some hint by code?

Comment: I'm assuming your console.log is logging the responses?  If so, then you just need to append it to the page some where.  Have you looked in the [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com) to see what methods are available for manipulating the page?

Comment: I'm doing that with this line, isn't it? $("#contents").load("cal.php", showValues );

Comment: You are logging to the console.  You are not appending to the page.  `.load()` will append to the page.  But `$.ajax` will not automatically append to the page.

Comment: The final step probably is very easy.. I just don't see how.

Comment: Take some time to review the API.  There is a whole section around manipulating the DOM.  https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: What exactly does "cal.php" log to your console?

Comment: @jasen: Nothing, it only shows an array dump of the stuff that put in it.

Comment: Something doesn't function as needed.
After clicking through the selectable options, the console log doubles it requests per click. Also I can't get the output I want. Thanks for your help so far, I'm losing my patience at the moment because I just don't see the logic and the missing peaces.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to bind a trigger to an event. You already have this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
```

Now, you want your function to fire off an AJAX POST request to cal.php.

```
function showValues() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'cal.php',
        data: str
    });
}
```

You need to capture the response and update your page. I don't know what your php script does so I'm assuming it returns html output.

```
function showValues() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'cal.php',
        data: str
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        $("#results").html(result);
    });
}
```

If it does not return html, then you'll need to parse the result in JavaScript and generate the appropriate DOM elements.

Finally,

```
$("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );

function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'cal.php',
        data: str
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        $("#results").html(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far ;)
It doesn't do any realtime firing.
It might be handy if I tell what I want to buid.

1 dropdown with agenda options (Public agenda, Private Agenda, Test Agenda)
The second part is a calander working with (in my case) a href's.
When making a selection in the dropdown and selecting a date in the agenda a div should be fuild with the agenda day depending on the selection.
It has te be realtime.
Perhaps it is very easy to build.. I just can't seem to get it done.
Perhaps it shouldn't made with ajax / jquery.. I'm currently clueless.
Suggestions?